# Required type: File Provided: FileInputStream while trying to run Jmeter in Java

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I was trying to run Jmeter from java using the help from
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line
In the lines

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/path/test.jmx");
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
```

But it shows a error in loadTree that it requires type File and we have given FileInputStream, but everywhere else it runs perfectly and if I convert it to file it shows a error while trying to run.

Comment: There is no such method as `new File(FileInputStream)`. Possibly you mean `new File("/path/test.jmx")`, and maybe you don't need the `FileInputStream` at all, but it's anybody's guess.

Comment: And 'it shows an error' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter 5.6](https://lists.apache.org/thread/yw1zgbnc106frjc9lc4pgnbgo5mjss41) the [JavaDoc states](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.html#loadTree-java.io.File-)

> public static HashTree loadTree(File file)
> throws IOException
>
> Load a Test tree (JMX file)
>
> Parameters:
> file - the JMX file
> Returns:
> the loaded tree

So it should be

```
File in = new java.io.File("/path/test.jmx");
HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
```

You might also be interested in [JMeter DSL project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dsl) which provides handy API for creating JMeter test plans from Java

Comment: Just as I suspected.

Comment: I don't need to make jmeter test from java. I have 1000+ jmeter test which I wan to run in java or I will physically have to convert each one to Rest Assured. Is there a way to run Jmeter Test in java without jmeter dependency. I don't want the user to need to download Jmeter.

Comment: You need JMeter to run a JMeter test so it has to be present somehow on the machine where you're intending to run it. JMeter test execution options which automatically download JMeter I'm aware of are [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) and [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/). However you need to have either Maven or Taurus installed.

Comment: @chirayuaggarwal43 So why are you writing Java code? And asking questions about it?